# Cannot read property 'then' of undefined with JavaScript promises

Tags: javascript, promise, return, undefined

I understand at first glance this may look like a duplicate but I have seen all the answers for that tell me to put a return in but that is not working.

this is my function:

```
function removePastUsersFromArray(){
  pullAllUsersFromDB().then(function(users_array){
  var cookie_value = document.cookie.split('=') [1];
  const promises = []
    for (var i = 0; i < _USERS.length; i++) {
      if (_USERS[i].useruid == cookie_value){
      var logged_in_user = _USERS[i].useruid;
        promises.push(
          onChildValue(rootRef, 'users/' + logged_in_user + '/disliked_users/').then(formatUsers)
        )
        promises.push(
          onChildValue(rootRef, 'users/' + logged_in_user + '/liked_users/').then(formatUsers)
        )
      }
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
  })
};
```

and I get the error at this function:

```
function displayRemovedPastUsersFromArray(){
  removePastUsersFromArray().then(function(promises){
```

basically saying that my `removePastUsersFromArray` is undefined. but it isn't as it clearly exists above and returns promises??

Comment: `basically saying that my removePastUsersFromArray is undefined` - no, it's saying that the fiunction `removePastUsersFromArray` **RETURNS** undefined, which it clearly does, as it does not return *anything at all*

Comment: try `return pullAllUsersFromDB( ..... rest of your code`

Comment: cheers chipper!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> basically saying that my `removePastUsersFromArray` is undefined

No, it says that the `removePastUsersFromArray()` call returned `undefined`, as that's what you're trying to call `then` upon.

> it clearly exists above and returns promises?

It exists, yes, but it doesn't return anything. The `return` you have is inside the `then` callback, but the function itself does not have a `return` statement. `return` the promise that results from the chaining:

```
function removePastUsersFromArray() {
  return pullAllUsersFromDB().then(function(users_array) {
//^^^^^^
    var cookie_value = document.cookie.split('=') [1];
    const promises = []
    for (var i = 0; i < _USERS.length; i++) {
      if (_USERS[i].useruid == cookie_value){
        var logged_in_user = _USERS[i].useruid;
        promises.push(
          onChildValue(rootRef, 'users/' + logged_in_user + '/disliked_users/').then(formatUsers)
        );
        promises.push(
          onChildValue(rootRef, 'users/' + logged_in_user + '/liked_users/').then(formatUsers)
        );
      }
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
  })
};
```